# Java: nested method doesn't compile

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and having some problem in Java. I learned about static variables and tried to implement it and worked fine, but if i'm implementing static variable in the nested methods, the variable is not getting updated

```
public class MyClass {
    private static int[] a = new int[5];

    public void firstMethod() {
        public void secondMethod() {
            for(int i=0;i<5:i++) {
                public void thirdMethod() {
                   a[i] = i;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(a[0]); // Doesn't show 0
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any mistake in the above code? If this is not possible, then any other solution? Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: Java does not support "nested methods". What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Any other solution to what? Why do you think you need three nested methods to initialize an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods can't be nested in Java. That's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code as posted bears only a superficial resemblance to Java. There is a facility for using executable code to initialize a static field:

```
  private static int[] a = new int[5];
  static {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
      a[i] = i;
    }
  }
```